# Android GPS Application Sometimes Crashing

Tags: java, android, gps

I have an application that has a GPS button to get your location and also a Google Maps place picker. This works fine most of the time as long as you have manually turned on the location for the application. The alert icon does not appear to get you to turn on the location like it should, it also randomly gives the following error:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> ```
>               --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>               Process: com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication, PID: 2443
>               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a
> ```
>
> null object reference
>                         at com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication.SearchScreen.onLocationChanged(SearchScreen.java:391)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   Application terminated.

I will attach the code below:

```
public class SearchScreen extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication";

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private GridViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listType;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listIcon;
    private String repairtype;
    private GridView gridView;

    private TextView tv;

    private Button contBtn;
    private Button googleLocBtn;
    private Button gpsBtn;
    private boolean setGPSloc = false;

    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;

    private TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    private TextView mLongitudeTextView;
    private TextView tv2;

    Double longitude;
    Double latitude;

    public static SearchScreen newInstance(){
        SearchScreen fragment = new SearchScreen();
        return fragment;
    }

    public SearchScreen(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        checkLocation();


    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

         tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        prepareList();
        repairtype ="";

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_TextDateTime);
        btn_date = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_datePicker);

        btn_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDate();
            }
        });

        contBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        contBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TechnicianListView.class);
                intent.putExtra("message", repairtype);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gpsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv2.setText("" + getMyPosAddress(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude()));
            }
        });


        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById((R.id.textView));


        updateTextLabel();


        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), listType, listIcon);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DEBUG " + mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                repairtype = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            }
        });

        googleLocBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.googleLocBtn);
        googleLocBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findPlace(v.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
            }
        });


        return view;
    }



    //Calling method DateFormat and Calendar
    DateFormat formatDateTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Creating Vars
    private TextView text;
    private Button btn_date;


    private void updateDate() {
        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), d, dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }


    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateTextLabel();
        }
    };


    private void updateTextLabel() {
        text.setText(formatDateTime.format(dateTime.getTime()));
    }


    public void prepareList() {
        listType = new ArrayList<String>();

        listType.add("di1");
        listType.add("screen1");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");

        listIcon = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        listIcon.add(R.drawable.camerabrokenicon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.screenrepairicon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
    }

    public void testBtn(View v) {
       // tv.setText("Welcome");

    }

    public void findPlace(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent =
                    new PlaceAutocomplete
                            .IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this.getContext(), data);
                Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber());

                ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView))
                        .setText("" + place.getName());

            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        super.onStart();
        if (client != null) {
            client.connect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        client.disconnect();
    }


    private String getMyPosAddress(double dbLat, double dbLon) {
        String addressString = "No address found";
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<android.location.Address> gclist ;

            gclist =  gc.getFromLocation(dbLat, dbLon, 1);


            if (gclist.size() > 0) {
                android.location.Address address = gclist.get(0);

                addressString = "" + address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getAdminArea();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return addressString;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        } startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
        }


    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you get a NullPointerException when onLocationChanged is called so your Location object is null.

You could put a check of if (location != null) so that it won't crash.

Comment: Its still not really answering why it doesn't ask me for my location if its not already turned on, which the code should do

Answer (score 0):

Add BroadcastReceiver, listening for changes in gps provider. By doing so, you will know when user turn off GPS. When that happens, change strategy for computing user location.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your manifest file for proper permissions and another thing If you are running in android m then you need to go to setting-->App-->select your app and go for permission enable it .. manually.

Or use in your code for asking the permission with a dialog box

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
```